# SSH onto Vagrant Box With Different Username

Tags: ssh, vagrant

Rather than ssh-ing onto my Vagrant virtual machine with a "vagrant" user-name and password, I'd like to use kevin/kevin.

I modified my `Vagrantfile` to include:

`config.ssh.username = "kevin"`

Then, I ran `vagrant reload`.

The following output showed up:

```
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. This can
mean a number of things.
```

However, I could still ssh onto my vagrant box using `vagrant/vagrant`, yet I I couldn't ssh onto the box with a user-name and password of kevin/kevin or kevin/vagrant.

Note that I also tried this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924122/409976), but I could only ssh onto the box with user-name `vagrant`, not `kevin` (even though it's specified in the `Vagrantfile`).

How can I configure my Vagrantfile so that I can ssh using user-name `kevin`?

Comment: If you can ssh in yourself using `vagrant`, but not Kevin, then it sounds like you need to setup the `kevin` user in the guest image. The `Vagrantfile` configuration only establishes the user to use, it does not setup users on the guest.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can ssh to the box using `vagrant` but NOT `kevin`, that's expected.

Most Vagrant base boxes have only 2 users with SSH access, `root` and `vagrant`. They both use `vagrant` as password, in addition, `vagrant` is configured for public key authentication using the insecure (why? see [Vagrant insecure by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715678/vagrant-insecure-by-default/14719184)) key pair provided in the Vagrant project on GitHub.

To be able to login as `kevin`, you'll have to ssh into the box and create the user (`useradd -m -s /bin/bash -U kevin`) first, configure public key authentication (many ways e.g `ssh-copy-id`, I'll leave it to you.)

You should be able to ssh into the box after creating the user using `vagrant ssh` if you properly set `config.ssh.username` in `Vagrantfile`.

Of course you can manually ssh into the box by (assume NAT is in use)

`ssh -p 2222 kevin@localhost`

or (on Linux)

`ssh -p 2222 -i /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.1/keys/vagrant.pub vagrant@localhost`

Comment: Note that I was able to simply create a user (`useradd ...`), destroy & spin up my VM, and then successfully SSH with putty using kevin/kevin log-in. But, I'm a bit confused since, as you had mentioned in "Vagrant insecure by default?," shouldn't `vagrant` and `root` only be able to SSH without keys explicitly configured?

Comment: You can ssh into the box with user vagrant, become root and then copy the file /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys to /home/kevin/.ssh/authorized_keys. Make sure the ownership and the permission of /home/kevin/.ssh/authorized_keys are OK (600 and owner kevin:group of kevin).

Comment: @Saule 's comment is the best answer.  Thread is old, but the search on this topic brought me here.

Comment: I also thought this was a good writeup http://ermaker.github.io/blog/2015/11/18/change-insecure-key-to-my-own-key-on-vagrant.html

Comment: That link Rob gave **is now dead**, so use [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20190917175007/https://ermaker.github.io/blog/2015/11/18/change-insecure-key-to-my-own-key-on-vagrant.html), courtesy of the Internet Archive 

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was looking for a valid user login from a while.

Answer (score 29):

Another solution, after adding user to Vagrant via your provisioning script:

```
## add kevin
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -U kevin -u 666 --groups wheel
cp -pr /home/vagrant/.ssh /home/kevin/
chown -R kevin:kevin /home/kevin
echo "%kevin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/kevin
```

add this to your Vagrant file:

```
VAGRANT_COMMAND = ARGV[0]
if VAGRANT_COMMAND == "ssh"
  config.ssh.username = 'kevin'
end
```

Now Vagrant will use default `vagrant` user to provision your VM, but once it's up, you can use simple `vagrant ssh` to log in as `kevin` via default Vagrant ssh-key.

This way you can ship your desired `Vagrantfile` and users just say `vagrant up` and `kevin` automatically becomes ready to use.

Comment: Do you know how could one store the password as well? Doing config.ssh.password doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Create a vagrant file like the one below. Note that we are bootstrapping the vagrant user to immediately change to the 'kevin' user that we created.

```
bootstrap = <<SCRIPT
  useradd -m kevin --groups sudo
  su -c "printf 'cd /home/kevin\nsudo su kevin' >> .bash_profile" -s /bin/sh vagrant
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.host_name = "kevin"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "#{bootstrap}", privileged: true
end
```

now ssh into the vm:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

kevin@kevin:/home/vagrant$
```

Comment: Nice, I like the self-sufficient nature of this.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a hack, but you could add the line `sudo su - kevin` to your .bash_profile file and add kevin to the sudoers file with no password.

This will change the current user to kevin when logging in as the vagrant user from the command line.

The advantage of this approach is that NAT does not need to be enabled.

Comment: this is such a hack! but it is simple and i like it.

Answer (score 2):

i find a easy way to achieve this by copy the .ssh to the user, such as your user name is `alice`

```
sudo su -
cp -r /home/vagrant/.ssh/ /home/alice/
chown -R alice:alice  /home/alice/.ssh
```

Then add config in the Vagrantfile:

```
# ...
config.ssh.username = 'alice'
# ...
```