# Connect to Vagrant machine with SSH and custom user

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

Here is the problem. After `vagrant up` in an Ubuntu 12.04 box, I create a custom user:

```
sudo useradd -m USER_NAME
```

And I add it to the same groups than the `vagrant` user. After that, I try to login with SSH but I can't find the way. I generate a SSH key pair with `ssh-keygen` , and set the following option in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.ssh.username = "USER_NAME"
```

So doing `vagrant ssh` allows me to enter the user password and log in as that user, but not directly with a SSH key pair. I think that I have to set up the config variable:

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = ""
```

But I don't know how... What path to set and where to place the public and private keys. It is probably a more conceptual problem with SSH than with Vagrant, but I've been with this for hours, any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the answer here: [SSH onto Vagrant Box With Different Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643177/ssh-onto-vagrant-box-with-differeant-username)

To troubleshoot:

1. make sure the user has a login shell
   `grep user_name /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 7`
2. I haven't tried the config.ssh parameters but you should be able to test the ssh login by using

`ssh -p 2222 USER_NAME@localhost`

or (on Linux)

`ssh -p 2222 -i /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.2/keys/vagrant.pub USER_NAME@localhost`

If you see error messages, enable ssh verbose logging by adding `-vvv`. You should be able to figure out the cause and take it from there.