# vagrant ssh keys chicken and egg

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

I use vagrant with a 3rd party linux box.

The box has the default vagrant/vagrant credentials.

In my Vagrantfile I want it to use ssh so I have this

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

In my bootstrap script I want to add my public key to authorized_keys. This works if I do it post VM creation.

But when I re-provision the VM from scratch, the VM has not yet received the public key through my bootstrap shell script.

How can I have vagrant install my public key in authorized_keys and authenticate with vagrant/vagrant until this has happened? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that works

Based on this [Vagrant insecure by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715678/vagrant-insecure-by-default)

Where we have

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa", \ 
    "#{ENV['HOME']}/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
```

This seems to have the effect that vagrant tries keys until it finds one that works (the example enumerates host file system paths too - very nice indeed.)